# Many to One Unidirectional relation in symfony2 has "No Association error"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, many-to-one

I am trying to create a many to one unidirectional relationship between two tables. `dateTime` and `availibilityList` are two entities, one list may have multiple date and time.

I added the annotations likewise in the entity dateTime but it is showing me this error:

> {
>   code: 500
>   message: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'd WHERE d.offerAvailibilityId': Error: Class StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity\availibilityList has no association named dateTime"
>   }

I updated my schema from the terminal by using this:

```
sudo php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It says : your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

dateTime Entity:

```
<?php

 namespace StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * dateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 *   @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity\dateTimeRepository")
 */
  class dateTime
  {
  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="date")
 */
private $startDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="date")
 */
private $endDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="startTime", type="time")
 */
private $startTime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="endTime", type="time")
 */
private $endTime;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=55)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var DateTime $offerAvailibilityId
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AvailibilityList")     
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offerAvailibilityId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $offerAvailibilityId;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set startDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $startDate
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setStartDate($startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate;
}

/**
 * Set endDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $endDate
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setEndDate($endDate)
{
    $this->endDate = $endDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEndDate()
{
    return $this->endDate;
}

/**
 * Set startTime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $startTime
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setStartTime($startTime)
{
    $this->startTime = $startTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getStartTime()
{
    return $this->startTime;
}

/**
 * Set endTime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $endTime
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setEndTime($endTime)
{
    $this->endTime = $endTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEndTime()
{
    return $this->endTime;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Set offerAvailibilityId
 *
 * @param integer $offerAvailibilityId
 * @return dateTime
 */
public function setOfferAvailibilityId($offerAvailibilityId)
{
    $this->offerAvailibilityId = $offerAvailibilityId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get offerAvailibilityId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getOfferAvailibilityId()
{
    return $this->offerAvailibilityId;
}
}
```

The function in repository i am calling in controller.

```
    public function findOpeningDetailById($id)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('list')
        ->from('StreetBumbApiBundle:availibilityList', 'list')
        ->innerJoin('list.dateTime', 'd')
        ->where('d.offerAvailibilityId = :id')->setParameter('id', $id) //This line is showing error
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $qb;
}
```

Is there any problem in my join query or the relation i made(Many to one) is incorrect?
Please guide..
Thank you

Comment: Remove the `@ORM\Column(name="offerAvailibilityId", type="integer")` annotation. The `@ORM\JoinColumn` is all you need to manage that column of the database, and you don't want to specify that it is an integer since you want the ORM to handle the mapping to type Entity\AvailabilityList

Comment: @Paulpro i did as told, this established a relationship between tables but still the error is same.. :(

Comment: I think that `->where('d.offerAvailibilityId = :id')->setParameter('id', $id)` will be expecting the parameter to be an `Entity\availabilityList` instead of an integer. Doctrine mostly abstracts away the `id` of entities, so that you work with entities themselves instead of their id.

Comment: You might be able to solve your problem by changing `findOpeningDetailById` to `findOpeningDetailByAvailabilityList` and passing in an AvailabilityList entity instead of an id.

Comment: @Paulpro How to pass an entire entity in this? and i did it from Id because need to show the details of list user clicks on, that will be done by id right? The app will get the id and accordingly fetch the row